# ggplot2 geom_plot values in the same bar

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization

I'm trying to plot a specific graphic on [ggplot2](/questions/tagged/ggplot2). I would like to plot like this one:

[image]

My code is:

```
library("ggplot2")

exec <- data.frame(
threads = c(2,4,8,16,32,64,2,4,8,16,32,64,2,4,8,16,32,64,2,4,8,16,32,64), 
msgs=c(100,100,100,100,100,100,400,400,400,400,400,400,1600,1600,1600,
       1600,1600,1600,6400,6400,6400,6400,6400,6400),
qtds=c(3778.2,6000,6000,6000,6000,6000,3756.6,7462.8,14666.2,24000,24000,24000,
       3762.4,7445.4,14284.4,27869.8,55877.4,93407.4,2934,5427.4,10717.6,17214.2,
       26222.2,37333.6))

ggplot(data=exec, aes(x=threads, y=qtds, fill=msgs)) + geom_bar(stat="identity", 
       position="dodge")
```

However, all the `msgs` are in the same bar, as shown in the image.

[image]

How do I fix it?

Comment: use `fill=as.factor(msgs)` or covert it to factor before in `exec`. Since ggplot thinks its a numeric it would "group" on it so you don't get the dodging behavior

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to convert the integers to factors. Using as.factor() to converted.

```
library("ggplot2")

exec <- data.frame(threads = c(2,4,8,16,32,64,2,4,8,16,32,64,2,4,8,16,32,64,2,4,8,16,32,64),  msgs=c("100 msg/min","100 msg/min","100 msg/min","100 msg/min","100 msg/min","100 msg/min","400 msg/min","400 msg/min","400 msg/min","400 msg/min","400 msg/min","400 msg/min","1600 msg/min","1600 msg/min","1600 msg/min","1600 msg/min","1600 msg/min","1600 msg/min","6400 msg/min","6400 msg/min","6400 msg/min","6400 msg/min","6400 msg/min","6400 msg/min"),
        qtds=c(3778.2,6000,6000,6000,6000,6000,3756.6,7462.8,14666.2,24000,24000,24000,3762.4,7445.4,14284.4,27869.8,55877.4,93407.4,2934,5427.4,10717.6,17214.2,26222.2,37333.6))

ggplot(data=exec, aes(x=as.factor(threads), y=qtds, fill=msgs)) +
geom_bar(stat="identity", position="dodge") +
scale_fill_discrete(name = "Msgs") +
  xlab("Threads") +
  ylab("Qtds") +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(legend.position = c(0.22,0.85))
```

[image]

Comment: It seems nice. But only a question. Is there a way to I change to order? For example: The correct order has to be 100msg/min, then 400 not 1600.

Comment: You need to sort in order right. So we can use the "levels." Let's go!!
Creating a table with the values of msgs:
`msg <- table(exec$msgs)` 
getting the names ordered:
`msg_level <- names(msg)[c(1,3,2,4)]`
creating a new column in exec df with the values of msgs with the levels ordered:
`exec$msgs_level <- factor(exec$msgs, levels = msg_level)`

, and now you use this in ggplot code: `fill=msgs_level`